# Is it a bad idea to write the Dispose/Close method to be asynchronous?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, dispose

Instead of doing the cleanup on the same thread (or launching a background thread and blocking till it completes) start the cleanup on a "background" (IsBackground = false, so it doesn't get terminated prematurely) thread and return immediately.

When is this a bad idea and how bad? Is this ever a good idea?

Comment: Is this an abstract thought or do you have a real unmanaged resource that's taking a lot of time to tear down (if so, what is it, I'm intrigued)?

Comment: More of an abstract thought. I was just looking over some IDisposable IO objects and thought "You should try to do all IO asynchronously because god knows how long it's gonna take. Wait, does this apply to destructors too? If so, then why not make them asynchronous by default (in using blocks)?"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the GC runs on a dedicated thread so it is in effect concurrent, i.e. the object is marked for collection and your app continues to execute. That's true for the client profile at least, I think the server profile may have the GC blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing the `Dispose()` from the `IDisposable` with an asynchronous cleanup violates the  [Liskov Subsitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) as one would expect the resources to be available again immediately after the call.

I suppose this is some optimization needed because of frequent allocation/deallocation, which would mean that in the end you might just **shift the problem to an increasing amount of objects pending to be disposed in the background thread**. That will lead to memory shortage over a longer time and need some synchronization to make sure the amount of these objects doesn't grow to the sky.

Like Lazarus said, a more adequate solution could be to have a [pool of reusable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

Comment: Just out of curiosity could you expand on how an async implementation in a Dispose method violates the LSP? I'm fairly new to it and I feel I'm missing something here.

Comment: LSP means that each object implementing IDisposable should have the same strong semantics. If you consider the example of a Stream to a file exclusively, if you close it, you can immediately after the Dispose/Close open another Stream to the file. That would not be the case if the Dispose would be asynchronous, leading to a LSP violation in my opinion.

Comment: In some cases, an asynchronous Dispose would violate the LSP.  In other cases it would not.  An async Dispose may be safe for fungible resources (e.g. GdiHandles) where nobody's apt to care when a particular handle gets released, but one wants to avoid having abandoned handles pile up; it may also be useful in cases where one can defer any attempts to use a resource whose cleanup has been deferred until after such time as the cleanup is complete.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'd want to look hard at the time to dispose of your unmanaged resource compared with that of initiating the background thread. If it's a heavily used process you could find this generating a significant overhead, if nothing else.

If the unmanaged resource is very expensive to create and destroy then perhaps you could look at maintaining a common instance or pool of instances for the life of your app.

Answer (score 1):

One place you wouldn't want to do this is if your object to holding some limited resources that other threads might be waiting to use.

I'm very interested to see other answers, as I think this is an interesting idea, and might be a nice way in some cases to return data to the user faster.

Answer (score 0):

A Dispose method should not return until all expected effects that other code may rely upon have been completed.  It is reasonable for Dispose to defer cleanup tasks when doing so will not break other code's expectations.  For example, the Dispose method for a connection pooling class might immediately add Disposed connections to a pool without closing them, and have a background thread close connections that haven't been used for awhile.  If there is a limit to how many different connections may be open, and a request can't be satisfied because the pool is full of cached (but presently unused) connections which aren't suitable for the present request, the "Open" method must be able to expedite the cleanup of the pool.